# Is it possible to apply an image to the quick links tile layout in SharePoint online and fill its entire space?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a quick links web part I am using for my SharePoint O365 site. I am using the Tile Layout option and want to know how I can fill the entire tile with an image I want to apply. Is this possible and if so, how??? I tried applying a custom image but the image does not fill the entire space, just the center of the tile and its small. I used the "fill space" option and it made the tiles way to big and disproportioned to the rest of my web parts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can start with your picture. Since you want to display it in the style of a tile, you need to modify the image to make it a square, without cropping you can add space on the sides or above the image. I know you want to display the whole image, so extra white space is inevitable. Because this web part will crop the image in the middle of the image to adapt to the size of the tile.

Below is a rendering of the two layouts：
[image: Tiles]
[image: Grid]

Comment: Xuyan Ding, I did try using the "fill space" and it worked but I was unable to use that option as the tiles were larger and not the size I needed. Thanks for your help tho!